# How to do a random number?

Tags: c#, random

I have a error trying to do the following code

```
Random r = new Random();
r.Next(10, 100);
```

But I have a error:

> Error 1   'ChaseRP_Admin_Control.AdminCP2.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no extension method 'Next' accepting a first argument of type 'ChaseRP_Admin_Control.AdminCP2.Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Users\Someone\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ChaseRP Admin Control\ChaseRP Admin Control\AdminCP2\Random.cs 24  39  ChaseRP Admin Control

Comment: Uhm, did you create a class named `Random`?

Comment: You appear to have defined your own `Random` class (in `Random.cs`). You're not using System.Random from the .Net framework.

Answer (score 7):

You have another class named `Random` in your assembly. It doesn't have a `Next()` method, like `System.Random`. You need to either change the name or specify `System.Random` explicitly, e.g.:

```
var r = new System.Random(); //look at the difference.
r.Next(10, 100);
```

Answer (score 5):

> ChaseRP_Admin_Control.AdminCP2.Random

You made your own `Random` class, which doesn't have a `Next()` method.
Either rename that class, or qualify the original one with its namespace (`System.Random`)

Answer (score 3):

From the error, you have a class in your namespace `ChaseRP_Admin_Control.AdminCP2` that has the name `Random` that doesn't have a `Next()`  method. You can change the name of the class.

Alternatively, You can put the `System` namespace in front of the random to tell the compiler that you want the random from the system namespace not the one in your class.

```
System.Random r = new System.Random();
```

Comment: "You should change the name of the class" --- namespaces were invented to not rename a class as soon as you have a collision with someone else's class name

Comment: @zerkms, but in this particular case, I think the OP should change the name of class, I would never like any of my class name to be same as something provided by .Net framework. IMHO.

Comment: @zerkms While that's true, it's still generally a good idea to avoid using names of types in the `system` namespace, because odds are high users of your class will have a `using` for that namespace, thus causing a name collision.  When the colliding type is in a namespace unlikely to be used in conjunction with yours, it's not an issue.

Comment: @Servy: it's a good idea to give the semantically meaningful names. If there are collisions - you can always give a different alias with `using` (or use FQN)

Comment: @zerkms - on other hand explicitly creating collisions with well known system classes is questionable practice from my point of view. Indeed it is entertaining to see someone hit this issue... even more fun would be to define `Random.Next` to return 4 but it may be too cruel.

Comment: @zerkms I know that and was going to edit that as an alternative into my post. But then my internet today is crap and very slow. I just did that now. I also prefer not to give my class a name that is already a class name by default on the .NET Framework but the OP isn't forced to do that.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not saying that you should name it "Foo" just because "Random" is taken.  I'm sure he can come up with an equivalent name that is still semantically appropriate.  Dealing with class name collisions is certainly *possible*, but it's still inconvenient.  While I'm not saying you should avoid class name collisions at all costs at all times, minimizing it by avoiding collisions with very commonly used namespaces is likely preferable.